# PHP Insert Numbers not working?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, numbers

I am inserting tags from a textarea into a database but the issue is that whenever I try to insert the album INT or the track INT it shows up as 0 in the database. If you see the PHP output the values are equal to 1 then when its inserted into the database with four separate queries it always shows up as 0.

```
<html>
<head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /></head>
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$tags = $_POST['tags'];
//$album = $_POST['album'];
//$track = $_POST['track'];
$data = preg_replace("~\s*[\r\n]+~", ', ', $tags);
$arr=explode(",",$data);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
$id = 'NULL';
$album = $_POST['album'];
$track = $_POST['track'];
echo $id;
echo "<br>";
echo $album;
echo "<br>";
echo $track;
echo "<br>";
echo $value;
echo "<br><br>";
//      echo "id ";
//      echo $album;
//      echo " ";
//      echo $track;
//      echo " ";
//      echo $value;
//      echo " inserted into the DB!<BR>";
//mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags (`id`, `album`, `track`, `tag`) VALUES (NULL, '$album', '$track', '$value')");
//mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `album`, `track`, `tag`) VALUES(NULL, '".$album."', '".$track."', '".$value."')") or die(mysql_error());
//mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags (id, album, track, tag) VALUES (NULL, '$album', '$track', '$value' )") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags(id, album, track, tag) VALUES('$id' , '$album', '$track', '$value')") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
</html>
```

PHP browser output:

```
NULL
1
1
this

NULL
1
1
is

NULL
1
1
a

NULL
1
1
test
```

Database shows the following entries with EVERY query I have tried

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6QQ9.png

Secondary link if first one fails

http://d4rkd0s.info/tags.png

Comment: You really need to take the time to learn about [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Even better would be to avoid using `mysql_query` entirely, it's extremely dangerous unless used very carefully, in favor of PDO or the `mysqli` functions.

Answer (score 0):

The value of those variables is the string `NULL`, you want to set it to a null value:

`$val = null;`

Better yet, it would be better to just remove the `id` column from your mysql insert:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags(album, track, tag) VALUES( '$album', '$track', '$value')") or die(mysql_error());
```

You don't **need** to insert all values in a row, mysql will put in the default values for the ones that you omit

Finally, it might be helpful to structure your insert as:

```
$sql = '<mysql insert statement here>';
//die($sql); //or use echo here if you want to see multiple
mysql_query($sql);
```

Uncomment the `die` during development, so you can see the actual string that's being sent to mysql

**ANOTHER ANSWER**

What type do you have on the album and track columns.  I presume you want a string there, and it appears they might be `int`.  Change it to `varchar(128)` and that should do it for you.

Comment: If you do remove ID from it altogether, make sure that the ID in MySql is set to auto-increment and unique

Comment: yes, that's a good point, i assume that id is a key and autoincrement.

Comment: Yes the autoinc is on and the id is primary key

i tried landons query and still got the following results

17
0
0
this

18
0
0
is

19
0
0
a

20
0
0
secondary

21
0
0
test

Comment: yeah, that's the problem, see my `another answer` above, you have the wrong data type

Comment: Album and track are both INT(5) and correspond to a number that is inside two other tables... albums and tracks.

Comment: I will try to work with strings and compare strings. But they will be numbers to tie to the albums table and tracks table. http://d4rkd0s.info/othertables.png

Comment: well try to print out the $sql string and see exactly what is being sent to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Are you converting your data to ints?

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags(album, track, tag) VALUES('(int)$album', '(int)$track', '$value')") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
  db_query("INSERT INTO tags(id, album, track, tag) VALUES('$id' , '$album', '$track', '$value')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```